# Why does the first command execute but not last two(stat and dialog)?

Tags: bash

I'm programming a script file(sh-file) that uses dialog and I have come to a point where I just want to put it a side for a few weeks since I get mad at searching for errors.

The script part that needs attention:

```
INPUT=/tmp/input.sh.$$ #Just a tmp file used for storing information
FIELDS=/tmp/fields.sh.$$ #Just a tmp file used for storing information

function view_folder_properties() {
    dialog --title "Choose a folder to view properties from" --dselect / 23 60 2> $INPUT
    location=$(<"${INPUT}")

    stat $location > $FIELDS
    dialog --title "Viewing permissions" --textbox $FIELDS 23 60
}
```

The problem is not the first two lines in the code, but when I want to execute stat and dialog it returns two lines of error which looks like this:

```
./lab-E.sh: line 232: stat: command not found
./lab-E.sh: line 233: dialog: command not found
```

I have been looking for the problem for almost an hour or two and still can't find any problem, that is why I am asking for your help.

Echoing $PATH variable on my system looks like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath_target_98747640:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Razer Chroma SDK/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA/WinNT/Bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet:/mnt/c/Users/<USERNAME>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/<USERNAME>/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/snap/bin
```

The dialog and stat path /usr/bin is in the $PATH above

```
root@LAPTOP-UOKAJ438:~# which stat
/usr/bin/stat
root@LAPTOP-UOKAJ438:~# which dialog
/usr/bin/dialog
root@LAPTOP-UOKAJ438:~#
```

Comment: My assumption is that these binaries are in a place that exists on your $PATH when run from the sell, but are not in the $PATH of your script environment. If you run `which stat`, you will see the fully qualified path. Try using this in the script, or adjust your PATH.

Comment: I can use the commands anywhere else in the script, except for at the end of the function view_folder_properties.

Comment: Include any code in your question as code-formatted text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, it makes it difficult for people to both search and copy-paste to try to help you. Please edit your question with the text (formatted as code preferably) instead of the image. Also, way too much information. This problem can probably be described in 2-3 lines of code, so please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your Q. Good luck.

Comment: You are overwriting a shell variable (`PATH`) that tells the shell where to find programs - as a result, it can't find them. Use a different variable name, e.g. `selDir` in place of `PATH`. Note that you should avoid using all uppercase variables in the shell.

Comment: I did not write over the PATH variable but it is changed from PATH to location now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat` and `dialog` are not shell builtins, they are external programs. Without full path, their location must be searched in the `$PATH` environment variable, which usually contains their common location (`/bin` and `/usr/bin`, respectively).

But you've changed $PATH on the previous line. The new $PATH probably doesn't contain the directories where the commands are located.

If you just want a variable to store a path, not the system one, choose a different name (`$path` would be OK).

Comment: I can use the commands anywhere else in the script, except for at the end of the function view_folder_properties

Comment: You mean you can use them **after** you change the value of $PATH?

Comment: Apparently the PATH variable is unchangable on my machine, have run this a number of times. May be because I am using Ubuntu as a subsystem on Windows 10

Comment: What happens when you change `$PATH` to `$path`, or maybe even `$mypath`?

Comment: In the function, nothing much just a variable name change.

Comment: Try running the script with `set -xv` added at the top.